Integral of $\int_{-r}^r e^{\beta y} \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}{d}\right) dy$
I'm looking for anything that might help me solve the integral below:
$$\int_{-r}^r e^{\beta y} \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}{d}\right) dy$$
With $\\{r,d,\beta,y\\}\in\mathbb{R}$, $\beta<0$, $\\{r,d\\}>0$
The function is essentially the angle $\phi=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}{d}\right)$ multiplied by an exponential decay, $e^{\beta x}$. In the figure below, you can see that $\phi=\arctan\left(\frac{a}{d}\right)$ and $a=\sqrt{r^2-y^2}$.

The only indication I have that the integral has an analytic solution is that the region is closed and well defined. The function is not analytic at $y=\pm r$ but is is analytical around it.

I've attempted a number of substitutions, integration by parts, and residue analysis. I've also tried to find it in some integral tables but I'm not sure what form to search it in.
The obvious substitution is $y=r\sin({\theta})$. This leads to
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{\beta r \sin({\theta})}\arctan\left({\frac{r \cos\left(\theta\right)}{d}}\right)r\cos\left(\theta\right)d\theta$$
Which doesn't seem any easier to solve.

Welcome to MathSE! Unfortunately, your post doesn’t fully meet this site’s policy (see how to ask a good question). I recommend that you edit your post. (1) You should provide some context to your question. Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? (2) Please tell in the post, did you try to solve it? What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

Why do you believe there is an analytic solution? And what is the source of the problem?

I've added some more information, hope it helps.

There's a couple of weird changes of variable names in your question ─ in the title you write $x$ but then use $y$ instead; and then about halfway down $b$ gets rewritten as $d$. It would help to edit the question to make these consistent.

Sorry about that, I was trying to use more standard variables but then when I added more info, I had my original names in the figures and missed a few things to change.

Here's a partial answer:
First, integrate by parts to yield
$$\frac{d}\beta \int_{-r}^r \frac{y e^{\beta y} \,dy}{(d^2 + r^2 - y^2) \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}} .$$
The substitution $y = r \sin \theta$ gives
$$\frac{r d}\beta \int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \frac{e^{\beta r \sin \theta} \sin\theta \,d\theta}{d^2 + r^2 \cos^2 \theta} .$$
By symmetry, we can rewrite this integral as
$$\frac{r d}{2 \beta} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{e^{\beta r \sin \theta} \sin\theta \,d\theta}{d^2 + r^2 \cos^2 \theta} .$$
Now, the substitution $z = e^{i \theta}$ converts the integral to a contour integral over the unit circle, $S^1$:
$$-\frac{r d}{\beta} \oint_{S^1} \frac{z^2 - 1}{r^2 z^4 + 4 d^2 z^2 + 2 r^2 z^2 + r^2} \exp \left(-\frac{\beta r i}{2} \frac{z^2 - 1}{z}\right) \,dz .$$
At this point we're prepared to apply the Residue Theorem. Denote the integrand by $f$. The singularities of $f$ inside $S^1$ are (simple) poles at $z_\pm := \pm\frac{i r}{d + \sqrt{d^2 + r^2}}$ and an essential singularity at $0$, so the Residue Theorem gives
$$\oint_{S^1} f\,dz = 2 \pi i [\operatorname{Res}(f; 0) + \operatorname{Res}(f; z_+) + \operatorname{Res}(f; z_-)] . $$
It's routine if tedious to compute that the residues at the poles are
$$\operatorname{Res}(f; z_{\pm}) = \mp\frac{i}{4 rd} e^{\pm \beta \sqrt{d^2 + r^2}} ;$$
their sum is
$$-\frac{i}{2 rd} \sinh \left(\beta \sqrt{d^2 + r^2}\right).$$
The essential singularity is harder to evaluate but manageable. Denote $\alpha := -\frac{\beta r i}2$, so that the exponential factor of $f$ is $\exp\left(\alpha \cdot \frac{z^2 - 1}{z}\right)$. Expanding in a series gives
\begin{align}
\exp\left(\alpha \cdot \frac{z^2 - 1}{z}\right)
&= \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!} \left(\alpha \cdot \frac{z^2 - 1}{z}\right)^k \\
&= \sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{\alpha^m}{m!} \sum_{k = 0}^m (-1)^{k - m} {m \choose k} z^{2 k - m} .
\end{align}
In terms of the parameter $t$ defined by $d = r \sinh t$ the rational factor has Taylor series $$\frac{1}{r^2} \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^{m + 1} \frac{\sinh (2 m + 1) t}{\sinh t} \cdot z^{2m}$$ at $0$.
Remark Alternatively, after changing variable to $\theta$, expand $e^{\beta r \sin \theta} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \beta^k r^k \sin^k \theta$ and interchange the integral and sum, which reduces the problem to evaluating the integrals $$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \frac{\sin^{k + 1} \theta \,d\theta}{d^2 + r^2 \cos^2 \theta} , \qquad k \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\} $$ and combining the results. When $k$ is even, the integrand is odd, hence the integral is $0$. If $k = 2 j + 1$ is odd, the substitution $u = \tan \theta$ rationalizes the integral, giving
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{u^{2 j + 2} \,du}{[d^2 u^2 + (d^2 + r^2)] (u^2 + 1)^{j + 1}} ,$$ which can be evaluated again by the Residue Theorem. This time, the singularities in, say, the upper half-plane are a pole of order $j + 1$ at $i$ and a pole of order $1$ at $\frac{\sqrt{d^2 + r^2}}{d} i$.

The method is brilliant, but I think something went wrong at the calculation of $\mathrm{Res}(f; z_\pm)$. Unless I messed up prefactors, your final answer is $\frac{2\pi d}{\beta r} J_1(\beta r) - \frac{\pi}{\beta} \sinh\left(\beta\sqrt{d^2+r^2}\right)$.
Numerical integration gives 1.048... (beta=-0.5, r=1.2, d=2.1) while your answer is -3.286...
Best guess is that $\beta$-dependence is wrong, deviation much worse with 2.684... vs. -264.1... (beta=-2.5).

I don't have the time to check your prefactors at the moment, but it's entirely possible that there's a computational error there. Feel free to check the computation of the residues.

Ok I believe I found the issue. The simple poles are fine (at most a minus sign), but the essential singularity is not. There is a $(-1)^{m-k}$ missing in the binomial theorem, but the bigger problem is that setting $z=0$ in the rational prefactor is actually not allowed (confirmed by numerical comparison). I think that is because multiplying the $z^2,z^4,\dots$ in the expansion with the $z^{-3},z^{-5},\dots$ from the other series gives additional contributions to the residue. Not sure how to fix this, but it also explains why the residue calculation in the remark seems so difficult

Ah, I think you're right. Thanks for the thought you've given this problem! I'm traveling but will update the answer when I can.

I added some more comments that are enough to derive an explicit series expression for the value of the integral, but the result is not really satisfying.
